# Partial class inheritance

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, inheritance

I am making a unit converter for windows phone but I'm having some problems with class inheritance.

I have the class `Measurement` which is supposed to be the top class for the graphical content in my program.

```
public class Measurement : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public void Convert(object give)
    {
        supervar.Comparer(this);
    }
    public WindowsPhoneControinput supervar { get; set; }
}
```

`Measurement` does not contain any graphical content, but it's subclasses do; And here is where I am having difficulties.

The subclasses: `Lengthco`, `Weigthco` and `Volumeco` needs to inherit from `Measurement` but the compiler says:

```
"Partial declarations declarations of 'Phoneapp1.Lengthco' Must not specify different base classes".
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please show the code for your subclass as well.

Comment: I think you'll have to provide us with a little more code than this.. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That happens because the XAML-code inherits from another class:

```
<UserControl x:Class="myNamespace.MyControl">
    ....
</UserControl>
```

results in

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    //...
}
```

If you want to inherit the control from another base class, you must use that in XAML, too:

```xml
<Measurement x:Class="myNamespace.MyControl">
    ....
</Measurement>
```

```cs
public partial class MyControl : Measurement 
{
    //...
}
```